# Can LaTeX change the behavior of core TeX commands?

Tags: tex-core, accents

We're implementing a system that generates TeX files from text entered into HTML forms, and a general question arose.

Quoting Donald Knuth's *TeXbook*:

> A control sequence of the other kind, like \', is called a control symbol: it consists of the escape character followed by a single nonletter.

A colleague is sure she remembers that sometimes `\"` should be enclosed in braces with its following character, e.g. `{\"A}` to get our German `Ä`.

I answered with the quote by Knuth, saying that we need not worry about it, since any nutty LaTeX macros that our users may throw at our files (aside from straight redefinition like `\def\"{foobar}`) cannot override core TeX language, and therefore we should be safe with `\"`.

Am I right?

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong.  TeX is capable of changing its own syntax completely, see [`xii.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/xii/xii.tex) for instance.  Hence `\def\"{foobar}` will override any previous definition of `\"` in the current group.

Comment: However, `\"A` does not have to be enclosed in braces to obtain `Ä`.  By proper LaTeX convention you should brace the argument though, i.e. `\"{A}`.  I think you should use UTF-8 and input `Ä` directly.

Comment: Welcome! Your colleague is right: when preparing a BibTeX file, a name such as “Müller” should be input as `M{\"u}ller`. However, this is a special convention only for `.bib` files. In LaTeX documents you type `M\"{u}ller` or, more simply `M\"uller`.

Comment: Is redefinition the only way to change the behavior of `\"`? And we're working on UTF-8, but we need to use math-mode a lot, and there Ä should be input as "A, as far as I know for the moment.

Comment: off-topic ... when placing braces around an accented letter, either as `\"{a}` or `{\"a}`, it affects (i.e. disables) kerning with adjacent letters.  so if it can be avoided, that's usually a good idea.  (but in the case of bibtex, it can't.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton true for `{\"a}` not so for `\"{a}` which is the official latex syntax, but equivalent to `\"a` just on general macro argument parsing rules.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Firstly `\"` is not a tex primitive, it is a macro defined in plain tex and also a macro with a different definition defined in latex, so it isn't that latex *changes* this macro it just has a different definition. (Plain TeX accents only have to work with the original 7-bit encoding of computer modern, but latex ones need to adapt to the currently specified font encoding).

The `{\"a}` syntax that you refer to is however unrelated to either definition, it is a convention required by bibtex to treat the construct as a single letter for sorting purposes.

But in general any macro package can redefine any tex command.

After

```
\let\def=\undefined
```

for example the tex primitive `\def` would no longer be available unless you saved it with an earlier

```
\let\saveddef=\def
```

or if you are using pdftex or similar extended engines that have a `\primitive` (or `\pdfprimitive`) command such that `\primitive\def` expands to the tex primitive even if the csname token `\def` has been redefined to be something else (or, as above, defined to be nothing)

Comment: Thanks, that sheds some light onto the inner workings of TeX/LaTeX for me!

Comment: Nit: I didn't know about `\primitive`, so I checked the pdfTeX manual. There, it appears to be named `\pdfprimitive`.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen ahh I'm getting too modern in my old age (it's called `\primitive` in xetex and luatex)

Comment: Well, it *is* a more sensible name, after all. The pdf prefix seems rather senseless, I think. (I haven't jumped on the xetex/luatex bandwagon yet, in *my* old age.)